# Filling pandas dataframe column values using df.div and conditions doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I am currently trying to set the value of the column `fractShrs` in my dataframe from an initial value of 1 to `(numShrs (t) / numShrs(t+1)` using this code

```py
def populate_fraction_of_shares(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame: 
    # Create a mask with all numShrs that are different set to True
    mask = df['numShrs'] != df['numShrs'].shift()   

    # Apply the mask to only divide by the different ones
    df['fractShrs'] = df['numShrs'].div(df['numShrs'].shift().where(cond=mask, other=1))
    
    # Normalize values dividing by the numShrs of the last row, so we start by 1
    df['fractShrs'] = df['fractShrs'].div(df.iloc[-1]['numShrs'])
```

My dataframe looks like this

```py
VWAP    VWAPAdj country dividend    dividendAdj freeFloatPct    numShrs pxAsk   pxAskAdj    pxBid   pxBidAdj    pxHigh  pxHighAdj   pxLast  pxLastAdj   pxLow   pxLowAdj    returnIndex turnover    volume  isin    name    currency    fractShrs
date                                                                                                
2023-07-03  176.503682  176.503682  USA 1.00    1.00    94.0    150.00  176.352591  176.352591  176.343429  176.343429  177.644518  177.644518  176.343429  176.343429  175.702037  175.702037  193326.88   5.547447e+09    31458200.0  US0378331005    APPLE INC COM   EUR 1
2023-07-05  176.535496  176.535496  USA 1.00    1.00    94.0    150.00  176.292623  176.292623  176.283409  176.283409  177.812933  177.812933  176.292623  176.292623  175.638415  175.638415  192191.75   8.271696e+09    46920262.0  US0378331005    APPLE INC COM   EUR 1
2023-07-06  175.203695  175.203695  USA 1.00    1.00    94.0    600.00  176.125087  176.125087  176.106719  176.106719  176.345505  176.345505  176.152638  176.152638  173.755691  173.755691  192673.94   7.954350e+09    45156008.0  US0378331005    APPLE INC COM   EUR 1
```

What should be happening is that the number of shares suffered let's say a split from 1 to 4 (like what happens in 2023-07-06, going from 150 to 600)  then `fractShrs` should go from 1 to 0.25, this is propagated from bottom to top, staying at 0.25 until numShrs change again and another calculation is performed.

My code applies a mask setting the rows where the `numShrs` change to True and the rest to False, and this works well for every row except for the ones set to True, where `1/numShrs` is happening, and with huge values I'm getting things like 6.35780394e-8, but I want to use the same value as `numShrs` in this case.

I have tried doing this

```py
    ... 

    df['fractShrs'] = df['numShrs'].div(df['numShrs'].shift().where(cond=mask, other=df['numShrs']))

    ...
```

but it doesn't work, I just want to use the current value of `numShrs` when the where condition is not matched.

Thanks a lot, apologies in advance for this long post.

Comment: Hello! I'm having a hard time understanding your question. It would help me if you provide some more sample data (only for numShrs), and the accompanying desired output :)

Comment: It was already fixed in the responde, thanks regardless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you attempted with `df['fractShrs'] = df['numShrs'].div(df['numShrs'].shift().where(cond=mask, other=df['numShrs'])`) is almost correct, but the where method returns the value of `df['numShrs'].shift()` where the condition is `True`, and `df['numShrs']` where the condition is `False`, so it will still divide by `df['numShrs'].shift()` when the condition is `True`.

To achieve the desired behavior, you may consider using the np.where function from NumPy to apply the desired logic as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def populate_fraction_of_shares(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

    mask = df['numShrs'] != df['numShrs'].shift()
    df['fractShrs'] = np.where(mask, df['numShrs'], df['numShrs'].shift())
    df['fractShrs'] = df['fractShrs'] / df.iloc[-1]['numShrs']

    return df
```

Hope this can help you!